# Dell Inspiron 15R (N5010) i3 2.6GHz Ram Upgrade Crash

Tags: memory, 64-bit, upgrade, ddr3, memtest86+

I have a Dell inspriron n5010 i3 2.6GHz M390 with 1333MHz 2GB memory with windows 8.1 32bit Operating System.

***I wanted to upgrade the RAM,***

i could not find any 1333MHz **4GB memory** So i bought a DIMM DDR3 1600MHz 4GB memory and installed it.

when i turned on the lap and went in to bios, it shows as total memory as **6GB**.
even after operating system did load and i went to my computer properties to check the RAM. as you see below,

---

**Processor: intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU    M 390 @2.67GHz 2.66GHz**

**Installed memory (RAM):  6.00 GB (2.93 GB usable)**

**System type:   32-bit Operating system, x64-based processor**

---

After upgrading the ram i decided to change the system to 64bit operating system, and started to format. when i try to install 64bit the **system crashes** and im getting a **blue screen**. im really sorry to say i did not able to get the message.

**i tried to run windows in 4GB ram stick yet i get blue screen error.....**

when i start the **mem test86** the computer get restarted.

please anyone can help me on this problem.

im sorry for my bad English... thankyou

Comment: I don't suspect it's a problem with the RAM. It's going to be really hard without the event dump for the blue screen. Follow this StackExchange answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396005/where-can-i-find-windows-crash-dump-blue-screen-crash-dump
And post a link to your error.

Comment: windows want start in single 4GB ram stick.... blue screen...

Comment: Odd. Do you have a working machine? Try setting up a bootable USB of [MemTest](http://www.memtest.org/) to check the integrity of your RAM.

Comment: when i start the mem test the computer get restarted...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the intel hm57 chipset in your laptop it seems that your motherbord do not support the DDR3 1600MHz ram. Bios can show the installed ram properly but win won't start. See the hm57 specificaton: 
http://www.pc-specs.com/mobo/Intel/Intel_HM57/1637